# Parallel Robots - Implementing close kinematic chains

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As I saw there is no official way for simulating close kinematic chains using URDF/SDF and gazebo.

2 questions:

1. For a simple 4 arm mechanism: Will gazebo spawn an SDF with 4 Links and 4 joints forming this type of mechanism?
2. If not, what is the right way of doing it?

Any direction would help.

Thanks

Nir

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7308/parallel-robots---implementing-close-kinematic-chains/) by [Niro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1007/niro/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NoellEagan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3942/noelleagan/) on 2017-10-12**:
Hi..i am a new user here. In my case several linear actuators are applying forces to the same joint in parallel - some of them spanning only one joint, some even two joints.As Gazebo7 features a graphical interface, is it possible to create those closed chains graphically?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Closed kinematic chains are not officially supported with URDF, though they are supported with SDF. Here is an [example of an SDF model with closed chain](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/863/tracksdriveplugin). Also, the PR2 gripper has a 4-bar linkage.

We are planning to create a [unit test for closed chains](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/863/tracksdriveplugin), but haven't done it yet.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hbaqueiro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5170/hbaqueiro/) on 2020-06-10**:
LInks broken or permission required. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Building on what is already said, I created  [a Tutorial on Simple Closed Kinematics Model](https://youtu.be/hglRGiNHRno) . Its just to have a starting point for anyone that is interested. It certainly helped me to understand it better and work afterwards on the fantastic [tracksdriveplugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/863/tracksdriveplugin) and my own projects .

[image: image description]

Here I leave you all the files I used, bith open and closed models sdf, their spawn launch files and the spawn sdf launch file:

[simple_open_chain.sdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15075411274514734.sdf)

[open_chain_spawn.launch](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1507541154893840.launch)

[simple_closed_chain.sdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1507541169330380.sdf)

[spawn_closekinem_example.launch](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1507541204338981.launch)

[spawn_sdf_robotdesc.launch](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15075412172565613.launch)

You should be able to have something like this:

Hope this is usefull.

---

Originally posted by [Duckfrost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2616/duckfrost/) with karma: 209 on 2017-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1